# The response of azure search indexer from the custom skill for the particular doc is :Could not execute skill. WebApi skill response contains errors

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

"key": "https://***.blob.core.windows.net/container1/Deployment%20strategies%20and%20best%20practices.pdf",
                "statusCode": 400,
                "name": "Enrichment.WebApiSkill.technology",
                "errorMessage": "Could not execute skill. WebApi skill response contains errors.",
                "details": "WebApi response contains both data and errors. Will not process Data.;Cannot process record without the given key 'text' with a string value",
                "documentationLink": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2100103"

Comment: How to resolve this error

Comment: What steps did you take when you received the error? Are you using Postman, writing a .net program, or doing something else?

Comment: I go through these docs: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-knowledge-mining/tree/master/workshops